# What's the best approach to "CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]

Visual Studio is showing this warning on every async task that I *do not want to await*. Why? I don't want to globally suppress all these warnings, because there may be instances I forget to await, but most of the time when this warning appears, it's because I'm intentionally **not** awaiting a task. What's the best response to these warnings?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014) explicitly says how to suppress this warning.  Did you try it?

Comment: Perhaps you should think more about why you don't want to `await` it

Comment: Note that when you don't await the task returned by an async method in some way, and the async part of that method is throwing an exception, that exception will disappear into a black hole to never be seen again. Which, if you don't handle the exception _within_ that async method, will turn diagnosing unexpected behavior in relation to the not-awaited async methods into the best fun you will ever have in your life...

Comment: Yep that's correct. I am handling exceptions inside of that task. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Charlieface, the reason I don't want to await the task is because the success of the task operation has nothing to do with the operation of the calling method and it should definitely not wait for it to complete.

Comment: "Fire and forget" has one problem re exceptions that has been mentioned above. It also has another problem: the calling code cannot know when the operation is complete, and thus it never knows when it's safe to exit the application. Application shutdown is normal and expected - even for always-on apps - to allow for updates. So IMO fire-and-forget should *almost never* be used. Updating a remote cache (e.g., Redis) is the only common use case that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it is returning a task, so to not await, the best way is to just set the return to something such as:

```
_ = SomeAwaitableTask();
```